# Twitter page in UIWebView redirects to 'sorry, that page doesn't exist' error

Tags: ios, twitter, uiwebview

In an iOS app I allow users to tap a Twitter button that takes the user to a specific Twitter page in the Twitter app, if installed, else a mobile version of their Twitter page in a webview. Currently, the mobile version is redirecting to an error page. This is also happening in Safari, while the exact same URL works great from a desktop computer.

- Open https://mobile.twitter.com/iamdevloper in a UIWebView or in the Safari iOS app
- Notice redirect to https://mobile.twitter.com/error/generic

[image]

Did anything change in the structure of the url? Is it just broken right now?

Comment: Takes me to some sort of login page.

Comment: @nhgrif That doesn't sound right either. Attached an image of the page I see from Safari (same for a `UIWebView`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to now be fixed. Must have been a temporary bug while Twitter was making updates to their mobile site.

Comment: iam getting this problem too :(

Comment: but when i open i safari, it works, just in the uiwebview it doesnt work